# Regular expression

Tags: php, regex

Regular expression para uma validação password. Quero que seja possivel no mínimo uma letra minuscula, uma maiuscula, pelo menos um numero e caractéres especiais (/,_,-, ... ). 
Exemplo: `$regex = '#^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{8,}$#';`

Como posso adicionar mais os caractéres especiais?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No mímino 8 letras, no mínimo uma Maíscula, no mínimo uma Minúscula, no mínimo 1 Número e aceitando especiais:

```
^(?=.*[a-zç])(?=.*[A-ZÇ])(?=.*\d)[\S\s]{8,}$
```

Aqui tem um link para testes [EXTERNO](https://regex101.com/r/YMOVJE/3).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas não quero obrigar a ter um minimo de caracteres especiais.

Comment: Agora pode ter quantos especiais tu quiser, inclusive nenhum.

Comment: @akm acho que finalmente entendi tua necessidade e atualizei a resposta com link externo, melhorou?

Comment: cool! (+1) `^(?=.*[a-zç])(?=.*[A-ZÇ])(?=.*\d).{8,}$`

Answer (score 2):

Você já tem quase toda ela, basta alterar o final:

`#^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d_ /.-]{8,}$#`.

Lembrando que `\w` é um resumo para `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

Ficando assim :

`#^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[\w /.-]{8,}$#`.